# Print the access logs before UrlRewriteFilter

Tags: spring, url-rewriting

I have an application in which currently I am using two filters.

First one is UrlRewriteFilter which is for re-writing the url.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Second is a filter which is printing the performance of each page, along with the url.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PerfLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.sia.saa.common.filter.PerfLoggingFilter
        </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PerfLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But in the logs only the re-written URL is being printed and not the original url.
**Please suggest a way so that URL re-writing can continue but in the logs only the original url is printed.**

Note: Post questions in case you need other details.

Answer (score 2):

Since UrlRewriteFilter uses `RequestDispatcher.forward()`, I guess you can obtain original request URLs in your logging filter as

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

so that you can log them.

Comment: Hi axtavt, the request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri") value in null while printing. Is there any other parameter I should look for?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to have the second filter before the first one? If the second filter is executed first, you will have the original url...