# How to access pretty URL from code

Tags: servlets, struts2, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using `UrlRewriteFilter` to make my URLs *pretty*. From within my application I frequently need to access the current URL. I do it like this:

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest().getRequestURI();
```

However this gives me the *ugly* version of the URL. How can I access the pretty URL before it is turned into ugly one by `UrlRewriteFilter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391899/print-the-access-logs-before-urlrewritefilter).

This worked for me:

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest().getAttribute(
            "javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the URLRewriteFilter class and override the doFilter method to store the request path in request attribute (Use this attribute to access the pretty url). Later call the super.doFilter method to let URLRewriteFilter do its job.